# Why does mysql_connect() return NULL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running my program on PHP 5.5.24,when I simply use :

```
$dblink = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

But the function return NULL, I try to use mysql_error() to find out what's wrong, but it also returns an empty string. I know mysql_* is deprecated after 5.5.0, but I'm dealing with a very old repository. It will cost a lot of time to change into mysqli. The function suppose to refurn false if the connection failed, no NULL. Why does it happen?

-----Update-----

Now I find that $dblink can not shown by var_dump(), var_dump($dblink) would get NULL but it's actually not null.

Comment: try call `PDO` or `mysqli` with this params, maybe it shows your problem

Comment: Pls share the exact code because it is possible that $dblink is simply out of scope when you try to check its value.

Comment: @Shadow I use var_export() just under this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

To show the result of mysql_connect(), pls use var_dump() instead of var_export(). I use var_export() and get NULL as return, but var_dump() shows the result is not null. That's strange.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39174 - exactly the same problem with proper explanation as to why var_export() does not work. Btw, when I googled mysqLconnect return null, the above link was the 1st to come up... All the hits had some kind of php programming error, this is why asked you to share the exact code with us.

Answer (score 0):

seems it can return null, search the source for cases when it can happen

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connect ([ string $server = ini_get("mysql.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysql.default_user") [, string $password = ini_get("mysql.default_password") [, bool $new_link = FALSE [, int $client_flags = 0 ]]]]] )

> Returns a MySQL link identifier on success or FALSE on failure.

I think U have to try:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
```

To see what happened.
I hope it is usefull.